# Using diff and fgrep to find similar errors in logs

Tags: bash, ksh

I have several hundred log files for jobs that were successful and some that were unsuccessful. All of the unsuccessful jobs have the the word "untranslatable" in them, so I can easily find all of the files using this command.

```
grep untranslatable *
```

So now that I have found all of these files, I'm trying to find out what else these files have in common, but i'm also trying to exclude all of the lines that are present in the successful log files.

I've tried these:

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' 20160120142000_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_fexp.log 20151214153516_yy_yyy_yyy_yyy_yyy_yyy_hist.dat.log | fgrep -x -f 20160120142000_xxx_xxxx_xxx_xxxx_xxx.log 20150904115502_zzz_zzzz_zzzzz_zzzz_fexp.log | grep untranslatable

diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' 20160120142000_xxx_xxxx_xxx_xxx_fexp.log 20151214153516_cc_ccc_ccc_cccc_cccc_cccc_cccc.dat.log |grep untranslatable


fgrep -x <(diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' 20160120142000_EMD_APPN_FEE_DETL_fexp.log 20151214153516_TD_EXT_LPS_PROC_MGMT_FORM_hist.dat.log) <(diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' 20150904115502_smr_sale_price_type_fexp.log 20151214153516_TD_EXT_LPS_PROC_MGMT_FORM_hist.dat.log)
```

What would be by best route if what I ask is possible? I don't know regex, but if that's something that would help, I'll probably read up on it.

Example:

Every file, successful or not contains this block of text.

```
563      ========================================================================
564      =                                                                      =
565      =          Logoff/Disconnect                                           =
566      =                                                                      =
567      ========================================================================
568 **** 14:20:55 UTY6215 The restart log table was not dropped by this task.
569 **** 14:20:57 UTY6212 A successful disconnect was made from the RDBMS.
570 **** 14:20:57 UTY2410 Total processor time used = '0.11 Seconds'
571      .       Start : 14:20:23 - WED JAN 20, 2016
572      .       End   : 14:20:57 - WED JAN 20, 2016
573      .       Highest return code encountered = '12'i.
```

I don't want to see this, because it, along with the rest of these types of blocks, make it really hard to find the problematic lines.

Every unsuccessful file contains this, however:

```
14:20:54 UTY8713 RDBMS failure, 6706: The string contains an untranslatable
560      character.
```

But, this alone is not enough to find the problem. These logs are 600lines each. I need to find out where I try to read this untranslatable character in my log, so I can change my query accordingly. It would be easier to read the log after the noise is filtered out. (The file I'm reading is millions of rows long, so I'm trying not to look there)

I realize I may be asking for a magic trick here.

I don't really want to disclose too much information about these logs, so a method is good enough. I can figure it out.

Thanks,

Maz

Comment: *Any* line in *any* successful log file wants to be excluded from the failing log files? You want the diff between a pair of failing log files after excluding all those other lines? If not can you better explain *exactly* what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to remove all of the noise that the successful and the unsuccessful logs have in common, so you're correct.

Comment: If you *really* mean that you want to filter out **every** line from **any** successful file and only show the **other** lines in the failure files then that's simple enough but the timestamps are going to complicate the matching unless you can define "regions" to ignore or patterns, etc. You need to give more concrete information about things.

Comment: Can you give me the code/command/reference that would help me do this ignoring the timestamps?

Comment: I could write patterns (for `awk` say) that match the specific example output you showed but I don't know what parts are static and what parts are variable and that makes it problematic. You need to be able to define **exactly** what you want to match (or not match) to do this sort of thing.

Comment: A wild shot (for 1 file first): Will `grep -vf okfile nokfile` work, with okfile a file without "untranslatable" and nokfile a file with "untranslatable" ?

Comment: @Etan Reisner : So the reason I'm being vague is because I don't want to accidentally disclose information that may get me in trouble with the company. Telling that awk is the way to go is definitely helpful and I'm fine with doing the rest on my own. I should probably specify that defining a method is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this

```
find . -name "*.log" -type f -exec grep -n -l "untranslatable" {} \;
```

this will show you all the files that contains "untranslatable" word.

Regards
Claudio

Comment: I already have that part solved. I'm trying to find out what else they have in common, while filtering everything that the successful logs also have.

Comment: could you please write an example of how is the log output and which is the output that you want? I guess that you need to write a script

Comment: Maybe I get you but correct me if I'm wrong: you have the "untranslatable" match in the unsuccessful log, then you need to find something in the successful log that can explain the error? is that your scope?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to filter out lines in an unsuccesful log using lines that are seen in a succesfull log, you need to make a file with filter-information.
Start with a large succesful log: `cp log.ok filter.txt`.
In filter.txt you will have line numbers and id's that won't match when you are filtering. So edit your `filter.txt` in such a way that the cleaned lines can be used during matching:
Translate

```
563      ========================================================================
564      =                                                                      =
565      =          Logoff/Disconnect                                           =
566      =                                                                      =
567      ========================================================================
568 **** 14:20:55 UTY6215 The restart log table was not dropped by this task.
569 **** 14:20:57 UTY6212 A successful disconnect was made from the RDBMS.
570 **** 14:20:57 UTY2410 Total processor time used = '0.11 Seconds'
571      .       Start : 14:20:23 - WED JAN 20, 2016
572      .       End   : 14:20:57 - WED JAN 20, 2016
573      .       Highest return code encountered = '12'i.
```

into

```
========================================================================
=                                                                      =
=          Logoff/Disconnect                                           =
The restart log table was not dropped by this task.
A successful disconnect was made from the RDBMS.
Total processor time used =
.       Start : 
.       End   :
.       Highest return code encountered =
```

And now start testing with `grep -vf filter.txt log.nok`